# I cannot navigate correctly in the bottom navigation bar - android bottom navigation view

Tags: android, navigation, fragment, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

There are 4 fragments in my application and 3 icons in the bottom navigation bar. When I press a fragment that is not in the bottom navigation bar, the navigation structure breaks down.

First, when I click on one of the food photos on the home page, I switch to the detail fragment. Then I switch to the basket fragment with the button. I cannot switch to the home page fragment from here. When I click on the home page icon in the bottom navigation bar, I switch to the previously open detail fragment. To solve this, I handled all item clicks in the activity, but it still wasn't solved.

[detail fragment and can't navigate home fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAPYM.png)

Main Activity

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class FoodOrderingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityFoodOrderingBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityFoodOrderingBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)


        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.food_ordering_fragment_container) as NavHostFragment

        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.bottomNavigationView, navHostFragment.navController)

        binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemReselectedListener{
            when(it.itemId) {
                R.id.foodListFragment -> navHostFragment.findNavController().navigate(R.id.foodListFragment)
                //R.id.foodDetailFragment -> navHostFragment.findNavController().navigate(R.id.foodDetailFragment)
                R.id.basketFragment -> navHostFragment.findNavController().navigate(R.id.basketFragment)
                R.id.favoriteFoodFragment -> navHostFragment.findNavController().navigate(R.id.favoriteFoodFragment)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

navigation graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/food_ordering_activity_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/foodListFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/foodListFragment"
        android:name="com.omersungur.foodorderingapp.ui.fragment.food_list.FoodListFragment"
        android:label="fragment_food_list"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_food_list" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_foodListFragment_to_foodDetailFragment"
            app:destination="@id/foodDetailFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_foodListFragment_to_basketFragment"
            app:destination="@id/basketFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/foodDetailFragment"
        android:name="com.omersungur.foodorderingapp.ui.fragment.food_detail.FoodDetailFragment"
        android:label="fragment_food_detail"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_food_detail" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_foodDetailFragment_to_basketFragment"
            app:destination="@id/basketFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/foodDetailFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
        <argument
            android:name="food"
            app:argType="com.omersungur.foodorderingapp.model.food.Food" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/basketFragment"
        android:name="com.omersungur.foodorderingapp.ui.fragment.basket.BasketFragment"
        android:label="fragment_basket"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_basket" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_basketFragment_to_foodListFragment"
            app:destination="@id/foodListFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/foodListFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/favoriteFoodFragment"
        android:name="com.omersungur.foodorderingapp.ui.fragment.favorite.FavoriteFoodFragment"
        android:label="fragment_favorite_food"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_favorite_food" />
</navigation>
```

bottom nav menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/foodListFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="Home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/favoriteFoodFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite"
        android:title="Favorite" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/basketFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_basket"
        android:title="Basket" />

</menu>
```

How I can fix that? Is it about backstack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. I used `setOnItem**ReselectedListener`  I should have used `setOnItem**SelectedListener.`